# Why do sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix and sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix have inconsistent function defintions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I am using sklearn and I noticed that the arguments of `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix` and `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` are inconsistent. `plot_confusion_matrix` uses `estimator` and `X` to construct `y_pred`, while `confusion_matrix` has `y_pred` as argument directly.

**What may be the reason for this inconsistency?**

Partial function definitions:

- `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(estimator, X, y_true, ...)` [where X should be X_test]
- `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, ...)`

Sources:

- [plot_confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html)
- [confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right that there isn't a consistent API design for this but there is an on going discussion for this issue [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15880).

One quick work around is [`ConfusionMatrixDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay).

example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_classification(random_state=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y)

clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression(random_state=0))
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

cm_display = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, [0,1]).plot()
```

Comment: Good to know I wasn't the only that found this inconsistent. Currently, I use this: `plot_confusion_matrix(clf, prep.transform(X_test), y_test)`, which is fine since it's only a small model.